# Perl - real time read log file

Tags: perl, logging, real-time, tail

In addition to using the module File::Tail (Perl extension for reading from continously updated files) o while loop.. according to you, which is the best way to read a big log file in real time?

Answer (score 2):

Read file until `eof`, sleep some time, clear eof flag on the file handle, and try again to read from it,

```
# open $fh..

while (1) {
    while (my $line = <$fh>) {
        # $line ...
    }
    # eof reached on $fh
    sleep 1;
    # clear eof flag on $fh
    seek($fh, 0, 1);      
}
```

You can `sleep` shorter by using `Time::HiRes` module

Comment: ... or using `select undef, undef, undef, $seconds` (where $seconds may be a fraction of a second).